# Typescript error ionic 3

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

So i'm trying to install this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic3-calendar and when i import it i get this errors:

> Class 'Nav' incorrectly extends base class 'NavControllerBase'. Types
>   of property 'goToRoot' are incompatible. Type '(opts: NavOptions) =>
>   Promise' is not assignable to type '(opts: NavOptions) =>
>   Promise'. Type 'Promise' is not assignable to type
>   'Promise'. Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'.
>
> Class 'Tab' incorrectly extends base class 'NavControllerBase'. Types
>   of property 'goToRoot' are incompatible. Type '(opts: NavOptions) =>
>   Promise' is not assignable to type '(opts: NavOptions) =>
>   Promise'. Type 'Promise' is not assignable to type
>   'Promise'.
>
> Class 'Subject' incorrectly extends base class 'Observable'.
>   Types of property 'lift' are incompatible. Type '(operator:
>   Operator) => Observable' is not assignable to type
>   '(operator: Operator) => Observable'. Type 'Observable'
>   is not assignable to type 'Observable'. Type 'T' is not assignable
>   to type 'R'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ***ionic3-calendar*** package is outdated, replace it with ***ionic2-calendar***:

```
npm uninstall ionic3-calendar --save

npm install ionic2-calendar --save
```